# dbSqlPackage provider not found

Tags: .net, msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am trying to use web processing pipeline with msbuild to deploy database dacpac using web deploy. I have following code in my project's .wpp.targets file.

```
<Target Name ="DeployUIConfigDatabase" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="dbSqlPackage">
        <Source>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\Database\Advent.PMW.UIConfig.Database.dacpac</Source>
        <Destination>{UIConfigContext-Web.config Connection String</Destination>
        <Action>Publish</Action>
        <AdditionalProviderSettings>Source;Destination;Action</AdditionalProviderSettings>
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

but when I try to build the package i get the following error

> Error : Web deployment task failed. (Could not find the provider
>   'dbSqlPackage'. Please verify that you've entered the provider name
>   correctly.) Package failed.

I tried using dbSqlPackage provider from command line but i get the same error. I have MSDeploy 3.0 installed on a windows 7 box. 
I can see that

> Microsoft Web Deploy dbSqlPackage Provider - enu

is installed on my box.I tried removing it ( as suggested in another post on this subject) but no luck

Comment: Don't use dbSqlPackage use dbDacFx as mentioned below.

Comment: doesnt look like we can pass sqlCmd variables to dbDacFx, see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093101/using-sqlcmd-variables-with-dbdacfx-provider-of-msdeploy, is there any other way to  pass variables to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dacpac provider in MSDeploy v3 is [`dbDacFx`](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/dbdacfx-provider-for-incremental-database-publishing). Also, your `Source` attribute should be `Path`, which doesn't require inclusion in `AdditionalProviderSettings`.

Btw, if you're using VS2012 (or 2010 with the latest Azure SDK) you should be able to include the dacpac using the publish dialog.

Comment: Is this provider only good for azure ? I am trying it on a local sql server2008 r2

Comment: It's possible it only works on SQL2012. I'd recommend asking in the [forums](http://forums.iis.net/1144.aspx).