# using SqlCmd variables with dbDacFx provider of MsDeploy

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2, msdeploy, webdeploy

I am trying to use msdeploy using dbDacFx provider to deploy my dacpac file. This database project uses a variable named UserName to create logins and users etc. Value for this needs to be passed during deployment time.

So i am doing something like ...

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:Sync -Source:dbDacFx="c:\dev\pmwuiservices\trunk\Build\database\Database.dacpac"-dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;Database=UIConfig", -setParam:Kind=SqlCommandVariable,scope=dbDacFx,match=UserName,value="IIS AppPool\ASP.NET V4.0"
```

but i get the following ( and by the way the url in the error message does not exist)

```
Info: Adding MSDeploy.dbDacFx (MSDeploy.dbDacFx).
Info: Adding database (data source=localhost;integrated security=True;database=U
IConfig)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Deploying package to database: Pending.
Info: Creating deployment plan: Running.
Info: Initializing deployment (Start)
Info: Initializing deployment (Failed)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Deploying package to database: Faulted.
Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
More Information: Could not deploy package.
Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:UserName.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_M
ETHOD.
Error: Could not deploy package.
Error: Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:UserName.
Error count: 1.
```

how can one user SqlCmd variables with DbDacFx provider in MSDeploy ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will confirm that I get the same error. Ahmed Elsayed's article http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/dbdacfx-provider-for-incremental-database-publishing, aside from having egregious typos, doesn't address sqlcmd variables either. I personally couldn't find the "real" reference like one would normally expect, such as the one for [dbSqlPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550081%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Furthermore, I found unexplained anecdotal and allegorical variation between "-setParam:kind" and "-setParam:type". Again without documentation to back it up and without having an actual working solution, it does appear that scope can be a *filename* (regular expression). That said, I've also seen partial snippets by which the authors are defining scope as the *provider* to which one assigns the parameter. Richard's stuff has worked for me in the past, so am I comfortable moving forward with his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The `scope` of a `SqlCommandVariable` parameter should be the filename you are applying it to, not the provider:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync ^
    -Source:dbDacFx="c:\dev\pmwuiservices\trunk\Build\database\Database.dacpac"
    -dest:dbDacFx="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;Database=UIConfig" 
    -setParam:kind=SqlCommandVariable,scope=Database.dacpac$,match=UserName,value="IIS AppPool\ASP.NET V4.0"
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i get following Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
More Information: Could not deploy package.
Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:UserName.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_M
ETHOD.
Error: Could not deploy package.
Error: Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:UserName.
Error count: 1.

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue after attempting the fix mentioned above... have you been able to find a resolution?